# Display full screen image using UICollection View

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using `UICollection View` to display 1000 images from `server`,when select on single cell that particular image should be show in full screen and when i swipe to left and right ,next and previous image should display respectively.
Till now  i displayed  1000 images in `UICollection View`,but i couldn't show the image in full screen,,please help me,thanx in adavance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can present a `UIPageViewController` modally. Each view controller will be view controller with just `UIImageView` subview in full screen. In delegate of `UIPageViewController` you can configure next/previous page.
You can check [UIPageViewController Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) for more information about implementation

Consider using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library to cache and load images asynchronously.

Comment: am loading image from server,so is that possible to show in UIPageViewController

Comment: Yes of course, show loading indicator in the center while image loading. As well you can display of the thumbnail as it will load quickly till you load the actual size image. As will make sure that you load the image asynchronously. Check my updated answer

Comment: yes ,using `SDWebImage` only i load the image into the collection cells,from  here only i stucked.i have no idea what code should give under `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`..can you provide some sample code,thanx for u help

Comment: You will present `UIPageViewController` modally. Give it the selected image index as attribute and then load your pages. Check the tutorial I added in the answer in how to use the page controller.

Comment: Ok let me try ,thanx